# Word to describe the setting for a particular time?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, vocabulary

I'm creating an ad of sorts for an upcoming event without a set date. What's a word to describe the setting including weather/time of year/occasion for a particular time?

I'd use it in a sentence like , "Based on the _____ at the time, we may do one of these three options:"

I was thinking "environment" or "climate" but they don't seem to fit well because they connote more strongly the physical and weather aspects, not the occasion as much as I'd like.

Comment: Based on the "weather conditions"...

Comment: If you want something generic that encompasses all of those things you should just say situation or circumstances.

Comment: Or "Depending on the way things are going".

Comment: Based on the prevailing conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Based on the **[circumstances](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/circumstance)** at the time, we may do one of these three options:"

> circumstance[s]
>   A fact or condition connected with or relevant to an event or action:
>   [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/circumstance)

Answer (score 1):

I like "circumstances," but in an academic crowd or setting, you could also use the word "variables"--people will understand that you are encompassing both environment and practical aspects.

Comment: Good answer but it'd be better if you added a definition :)

Answer (score 1):

I will go with **situation**.

> : all of the facts, conditions, and events that affect someone or
>   something at a particular time and in a particular place
>   [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/situation)
>
> "Based on the situation [i.e. how things stand] at the time, we may do one of these three
>   options:"

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [***condition***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/condition) as it means:

> something essential to the appearance or occurrence of something else

[Merriam-Webster]

> The ***factors*** or ***prevailing situation*** influencing the performance or
>   outcome of a process:

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

"Depending on various conditions at the time, we may do one of these three options:"

Comment: Conditions (plural), perhaps?

Comment: @A.P. Of course.